# python mock on method returning mock rather than return_value?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

Consider the following (really simple) unit test file:

```
import unittest
from mock import Mock

class TestMuPE(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_01(self):
    mock_buffer = Mock()
    mock_buffer.frame_count.return_value(42)
    self.assertEquals(mock_buffer.frame_count(), 42)

    # => AssertionError: <Mock name='mock.frame_count()' id='4413645520'> != 42
```

I would expect `mock_buffer.frame_count()` to evaluate to 42, but instead it's returning a mock object.  What am I missing?

P.S.: I'm running Python 2.7.11 with the mock-2.0.0 backport loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the return value by using:

```
mock_buffer.frame_count.return_value = 42
```

Instead of:

```
mock_buffer.frame_count.return_value(42)
```

Comment: [facepalm]Doh.[/facepalm]   Thanks.